# Class terminology: "Data member" vs. "member data" -- which one is proper?

Tags: function, terminology, member

I think the common labeling of members of a class in most discussions are "data member" and "member function." Isn't that inconsistent? They do seem to sound natural, however.

Let me attempt to make sense of it:

- Within the context of class discussion, I think the terms "data member" and "function member" should be used.
- Within the context of scope discussion, I think the terms "member data" and "member function" are more appropriate.

Comment: data members contain member data.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "data members contain data" as the subject "data members" already implies to which the "data" belongs?

Comment: Also, the clause "data members" already implies an entity with "data." So, I'm not sure if your comment "data members contain member data" provides any useful info.